Rolling back an angular 13 to 14 upgrade and now npm update fails - peer dependencies
I was performing an upgrade from Angular 13 to Angular 14 and ran into problems.  I've reverted back to Angular 13, but now "npm update" reports peer dependency problems within the angular components.
My angular versions are:
Angular CLI: 13.3.11
Node: 20.12.2 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 10.8.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 13.4.0
... animations, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router, service-worker

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1303.11
@angular-devkit/build-angular      13.3.11
@angular-devkit/core               13.3.11
@angular-devkit/schematics         13.3.11
@angular/cdk                       13.3.9
@angular/cli                       13.3.11
@angular/material                  13.3.9
@angular/material-moment-adapter   13.3.9
@schematics/angular                13.3.11
rxjs                               7.8.1
typescript                         4.6.4

Warning: The current version of Node (20.12.2) is not supported by Angular.

My package.json looks like:
{
  "name": "app",
  "title": "ABX",
  "company": "SkyWare Labs Inc.",
  "version": "2.3.1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "clean": "rimraf ./dist",
    "start": "ng serve --port 4200",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "ng build --configuration production",
    "test": "ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadlessCustom",
    "test:watch": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "~13.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~13.4.0",
    "@ant-design/colors": "^7.0.2",
    "@sentry/angular": "^6.19.7",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^6.19.7",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.8",
    "@types/mixpanel-browser": "^2.35.6",
    "angulartics2": "^12.1.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.25",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "leaflet-easybutton": "^2.4.0",
    "mixpanel-browser": "^2.41.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^4.1.1",
    "ngx-material-file-input": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-webstorage-service": "^5.0.0",
    "nvm": "^0.0.4",
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~13.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^4.0.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.9",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.15",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.1.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.20",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "puppeteer": "^2.1.1",
    "ts-node": "10.7.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "ng2-charts": {
      "rxjs": "^7.4.0"
    }
  }
}


The error I am encountering is shown below.  I know I can get by this by using the --force switch, but am trying to fix the dependencies so I don't have to.
Why does "@angular/cdk@13.3.9" want to use "@angular/common@14.3.0"?
npm update
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: app@2.3.1
npm error Found: @angular/core@13.4.0
npm error node_modules/@angular/core
npm error   @angular/core@"^13.4.0" from the root project
npm error   peer @angular/core@"^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@13.3.9
npm error   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm error     @angular/cdk@"^13.3.9" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer @angular/core@"14.3.0" from @angular/common@14.3.0
npm error node_modules/@angular/common
npm error   peer @angular/common@"^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@13.3.9
npm error   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm error     @angular/cdk@"^13.3.9" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error


just revert to a commit before you started the upgrade

Thanks.  I should have thought of that.  I was too focused on finding the problem with the dependencies.
